# How to change all WPF Windows background colors?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

MainWindow XAML:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500">
<Grid>
   <Button Width="300" Height="30" Content="Change All Windows Background Colors To Yellow" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
   <Button Width="300" Height="30" Content="Show Me The Window1" Name="Button2" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1 XAML:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="500">
<Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow vb.net codes;

```vb
Class MainWindow
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each window As Window In Application.Current.Windows
        window.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myWindow As New Window1()
    myWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
    myWindow.ShowDialog()
End Sub
End Class
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run this WPF project.
2. Click **Change All Windows Background Colors To Yellow** button.
3. Click **Show Me The Window1** button.

Question: Why doesn't Window1's background color change to yellow?

Comment: To answer the *"why"*-part of your question: Because that window doesn't exist yet when you change the background color (note the **new** in `As New Window1()`).

Comment: Ok, lets make this a bit easier to understand. Imagine your windows are pieces of paper. They are white by default and you want them to be yellow when someone presses a button. You have two pieces of paper when someone presses the button "turn everything yellow", so you take your crayons and color both of them yellow. Then you get a **new** piece of paper - it's still white because you got it **after** you colored *all* pieces of paper you had yellow.

Comment: How about you do it yourself? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service you know. Understanding the problem and fixing it yourself will be a lot more valuable to you in the long run than taking a finished solution from the internet. Hint: JophyJob is on the right track, you simply need to learn how to use and apply styles - that's exactly what they are used for in WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Style to do this

```xaml
<Application x:Class="ChangeStyleHelp.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And put below code

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Style style = new Style 
    { 
        TargetType = typeof(Window) 
    };

    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow));

    Application.Current.Resources["MyStyle"] = style;
}
```

And add style to all windows (parent and child)

```xaml
<Window x:Class="SimpleWpfPageApp.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleWpfPageApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}"
```

Basically you are looking for WPF them just checkout this : 
[compiled-and-dynamic-skinning](http://michaelscodingspot.com/2017/06/30/wpf-complete-guide-themes-skins/#compiled-and-dynamic-skinning)
[managing-themes-in-wpf](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.in/2014/01/managing-themes-in-wpf.html)

Comment: var brush = new SolidColorBrush();
            brush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#ffaacc"));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.BackgroundProperty, brush));

Comment: Solved  `Dim brush As New SolidColorBrush
        brush = DirectCast((New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#ffaacc")), SolidColorBrush)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jophy.